# Elastic Stack (ELK) for multiple projects

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, microservices, elastic-stack, elk

I am new to Elastic Stack (ELK) and I am trying to set up the logging mechanism (ELK) for multiple projects with an optimal way.

The structure is as follows

- 2 - 5 projects, totally independent from one another
- all projects are architectured as microservices with docker or kubernetes
- each project on a single VM,
- all VMs within the same company VPN
- The projects will not be deployed in AWS or similar, their production deployment is on those VMs

The initial question is do I need an Elastic stack for each one component ?

Or one Elastic Stack common for all components? e.g. a dedicated machine to run the Stack and collect logs and metrics from each project-deployment

What components can be shared and not be duplicated ? e.g. share elastic but need separate kibana ?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a single cluster that can hold multiple lots of data - aka multi tenant

the easiest way to do this would be to put each data source into it's own index in Elasticsearch, and then use Kibana Spaces to keep logical separation of the data when it's being analysed